# Constructing an object with Ints and Doubles to a method from a text file

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

I'm having trouble Scanning a text file and assigning the data to variables in an object.

Here's my text file

```
1165,4.25,15
1305,1.80,42
1345,12.56,16
1388,7.42,30
1480,6.54,80
1495,8.36,48
1560,15.27,65
```

Now when I go to make the Inventory object I'm trying to set a delimiter of "," and then constructing it with the numbers in between but it throws an error for

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at Proj2.main(Proj2.java:18)
```

Here's my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Proj2 {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {

        Scanner soldScan;
        Scanner invScan;

        soldScan = new Scanner (new File("SoldSorted.txt"));
        invScan = new  Scanner (new File("Inventory.txt"));
        invScan = invScan.useDelimiter(",");
        while (soldScan.hasNext()){
            //System.out.println ("Product Code: " + strScan.next());
            //System.out.println ("Quantity: " + strScan.next());

            Sales x = new Sales(soldScan.next());
            //HERE'S MY ISSUE THIS DOESN'T WORK
            Inventory y = new Inventory(invScan.nextInt(),invScan.nextDouble(),invScan.nextInt());

            x.printSales();
            //y.printInv();
        }

    }
}

public class Inventory {
    int productCode;
    double price;
    int quantityOnHand;

    public Inventory(int code, double cost, int inStock) {
        productCode = code;
        price = cost;
        quantityOnHand = inStock;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        productCode = code;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setInStock(int inStock) {
        quantityOnHand = inStock;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getInStock() {
        return quantityOnHand;
    }

    public int postSale(int sold) {
        quantityOnHand = quantityOnHand - sold;
        return quantityOnHand;
    }

    public void printInv(){
        System.out.println("Product Code: " + productCode);
        System.out.println("Price: " + price);
        System.out.println("Quantity on Hand: " + quantityOnHand);
    }
}
```

EDIT: After a suggestion I changed the delimiter and now am receiving this :

```
Product Code: 1165
Quantity Sold: 24
Product Code: 1
Price: 1.0
Quantity on Hand: 6

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at Proj2.main(Proj2.java:18)
```

It's reading just the first "1" in "1165" as the first int, then "1.0" as the next Double...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have switched the delimeter from whitespace, to ',', when executing your second `invScan.nextInt()` statement, I believe Java reads all the whitespace up until the next comma on the next line. Since an Integer cannot have whitespace, java throws this exception.

EDIT: Adopted @igreen solution

```
invScan = invScan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(",|\\s*");
```

Comment: So for fixing this you should use regex like: `,|\\s*`

Comment: After changing the delimiter to igreen's suggestion it still throws the exception after one time through the while and just gives the first three numbers in the first field to the first three variables instead of the entire numbers. I'll edit the info in my OP